# Powershell function unnesting object in return value

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am having an issue with a powershell function,

the function should take an array of objects and split them into groups. it then puts the groups into an array

here is the function.

```
    function getRebootGroups(){ #Recieves allBrokerMachines result object

    $RebootGroups = @()


    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $args[0].count; $i += $maxConcurrentReboots) {
       $RebootGroups += ,@($args[0][$i..($i+($maxConcurrentReboots-1))]);
    }

    if ($RebootGroups.Length -eq 1){

    }

    Out-File -InputObject (ConvertTo-Json $RebootGroups) -FilePath C:\Citrix   \getRebootGroups.txt
    $numberOfGroups = $RebootGroups.Length
    Write-Debug -Message "getRebootGroups: $numberOfGroups"
    return $RebootGroups

   }
```

you can see i export the array to a json file so i can see what is happening. inside this function the objects are nesting fine. i end up with $rebootgroups[index][group of machines] as expected.

however if there is only one group the calling function evaluates this method to getRebootGroups[group of machines] which is unexpected.
if there are multiple groups the calling function evaluates this method to getRebootGroups[index][group of machines] as expected.

its like power shell see that the parent object is empty and trims it

here is the calling method.

```
 function testGetRebootGroups(){ #calculate reboot groups and check group size.

        $allMachines = allBrokerMachines $CTXProdCatalogs
        $result = getRebootGroups $allMachines
        $expectedNumGroups = ($allMachines.Length / $maxConcurrentReboots)
        Out-File -InputObject (ConvertTo-Json $result) -FilePath C:\Citrix\testGetRebootGroups.txt
        $result.Length 
        $numgroups = $result.Length
        if($result.Length -eq $expectedNumGroups){
            return "Pass - $numgroups groups created. (Group Size = $maxConcurrentReboots)"
        }else{
            return "Fail - $numgroups groups created. $expectedNumGroups groups expected."
        }

    }
```

I am unable to provide the input data for security reasons however the input data could simply be an array like...

```
$inputData = @('PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4','PC5','PC6','PC7','PC8','PC9','PC10')
```

I would really appreciate any help that someone can offer

Comment: powershell "unrolls" arrays when passing them via the output stream. you can get past that by either using the comma operator to wrap the object in another temporary array OR by using the more usual method of NOT holding the items in the function - instead, pass each one out as soon as you have it. then the calling code can accept the items into an automatic array OR accept the singleton into a forced array by [a] wrapping the call in `@(Get-RebootGroups)`, or [b] typecasting the $Var with `[array]$Results = Get-RebootGroups`.

Comment: Thanks so much. i though it would be some powershell quirk, I have just moved  the array declaration out of that function and set the function to just return $true to signify completion. Thanks again.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Comment: This is a very common gotcha. To anyone coming from Python, think about the powershell pipeline behaviour as "every function is a generator". That analogy shouldn't be pushed too far, of course!